# Какой лучший способ глубокого копирования по производительности?

Tags: javascript

Существуют много способов глубокого копирования, подскажите, что на данный момент является наиболее производительным при копировании объектов глубиной N и размерами X?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/4496422